# plot dataset and labels over multiple rows (jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning

I have the following code below which simply plots datasets (consisting of dogs and cats images) and their labels. I'm using jupyter notebook:

```py
train_path = 'dataset/train'
valid_path = 'dataset/valid'
test_path = 'dataset/test'

train_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['dog', 'cat'], batch_size=10)
valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(valid_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['dog', 'cat'], batch_size=4)
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(test_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['dog', 'cat'], batch_size=10)

# plot function, used to plot images with labels within jupyter notebook
def plots(ims, figsize=(12,6), rows=1, interp=False, titles=None):
    if type(ims[0]) is np.ndarray:
        ims= np.array(ims).astype(np.uint8)
        if (ims.shape[-1] != 3):
            ims = ims.transpose((0,2,3,1))
    f = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    cols = len(ims)//rows if len(ims) % 2 == 0 else len(ims)//rows + 1
    for i in range(len(ims)):
        sp = f.add_subplot(rows, cols, i+1)
        sp.axis('off')
        if titles is not None:
            sp.set_title(titles[i], fontsize=16)
        plt.imshow(ims[i], interpolation=None if interp else 'none')

imgs, labels = next(train_batches)

# we plot these samples of images and their labels 1 batch at a time.
plots(imgs, titles=labels)
```

If I use only 10 samples per batch as per the code above, this fits adequately along the notebook page width:

[image]

But if I want to change the batch size to more than that, say 100 samples (or any size) in a batch (i.e. in the code `train_batches = ImageDataGenerator()` change `batch_size=100`), and plot this, it will just try to squeeze it all inline on 1 row, as per the screenshot below:
[image]

How do I change this in the code so it plots all 100 data samples to fit adequately across multiple rows, rather than squeeze them all (to a tiny size) in a single row.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever put any argument for  `rows` in?

Comment: I didn't think about the argument 'rows'. That was obvious :) Thank you. Although now I have another issue with vertical spacing between each row, as the labels are overlapping with the images in the row above them: https://i.imgur.com/EEJ2W7f.jpg . How to have indentation/vertical spacing between each row to avoid this? I think whatever code that does this would go in the 'for loop', but how to add this indentation after each row?

Comment: E.g. `fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)` would make half as much space between rows as the image is tall.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, that worked :) And finally when I created the right indentation spacing, the bigger the indentation the smaller the images became: https://i.imgur.com/sHI9lkq.jpg. How to control the image size value? Or is this to do with the subplots sizes? By the way, I changed the `figsize` doubling the values (24, 12), but that only made the overall plot bigger, giving each subplot more space.

Comment: By the way feel free to put your comments as a solution rather than just comments so I can mark it with a green tick :)

Comment: I thought `Interpolation` agrument in `Imshow` with values such as  'nearest', 'bilinear', 'bicubic' are image processing techniques for re-sizing an image. So I tried changing that value but it didn't do anything.

Comment: The image size is just a result of the number of rows and the figure size. You cannot change it independently. (For the sake of argument, and without taking paddings into account, each image is simply `figheight / rows` tall)

Comment: Ok so it cannot be changed then. No probs. Many thanks for your help on the other solutions you provided. Appreciated