# How do I print sample images (preferably with class) after using Keras ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras

I would like to print sample pictures from my training batches that I have created with Keras as follows:

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255, horizontal_flip=True, 
                rotation_range=5).flow_from_directory('train', target_size=(256, 256), classes=[
                'bike', 'car', 'motorcycle', 'other', 'truck', 'van'], batch_size=12)
```

Ideally I would like the classes to show as well but right now I would be happy just to be able to show sample pictures. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57548144/plot-dataset-and-labels-over-multiple-rows-jupyter-notebook) but when I try that code with my train_batch like this:

```
def plots(ims, figsize=(12,6), rows=3, interp=False, titles=None):
    if type(ims[0]) is np.ndarray:
        ims = np.array(ims).astype(np.uint8)
        if (ims.shape[-1] != 3):
            ims = ims.transpose((0,2,3,1))
    f = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    cols = len(ims)//rows if len(ims) % 2 == 0 else len(ims)//rows + 1
    for i in range(len(ims)):
        sp = f.add_subplot(rows, cols, i+1)
        sp.axis('Off')
        if titles is not None:
            sp.set_title(titles[i], fontsize=16)
        plt.imshow(ims[i], interpolation=None if interp else 'none')

imgs, labels = next(train_batches)

plots(imgs, titles=labels)
```

it plots the classes as it should but only black squares and not the pictures like this: 
[image: black squares with classes]
As I said before right now I would be very happy just to be able to print sample pictures and it doesn't have to be an entire batch. (But that said if you know how to correct my code so the above code actually works I'd be grateful.)

**EDIT:** 
The pictured are plotted as they should if I remove everything that is in the parentheses for ImageDataGenerator. I tried removing just the rescale first but it did nothing. So Now my question would be; How do I create images with all of these variance (flipped, rescaled, rotated) so I can train a solid (or at least trying to be) model?

Comment: It might be to combo `rescale=1/255` + `.astype(np.uint8)` which basically sets all the pixels to zero? (it depends on the input images so I cannot be sure)

Comment: Thanks, I removed rescale but got the same result, what should I try with astype?(input images are .PNG 256x256 and RGB)

Comment: You can try to remove it. if it does not work, you can place a `print(ims)` somewhere inside the function to understand if you have only zeros, or if it is a visualization problem

Comment: As you said it is filled with zeros so something is def wrong. It must be in the very first bit then - the ImageDataGenerator - bit?  (as I have no trouble looking at the png.files....)

Comment: Yes, the problem might be the generator as well. I would try to debug it removing parameters, and testing with different images

Comment: Thanks @Andrea I'll do that. Is there an "easy" way to just plot a sample image without the class to easier find the fault in the generator code?

Comment: @Andrea Edit: Never mind I skipped the things inside the parentheses in the generator and I got the pictures. I guess the question now will be how do I generate flipped and different sized images of my images to create a good model.....Thank you again.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is the astype when setting "ims". I knew that it was something with the rescaling and tried different ways to juggle ims[i] and vmin/vmax. But when deleting astype I can use the parameters for ImageDataGenerator as above.

```
def plots(ims, figsize=(12,6), rows=3, interp=False, titles=None):
    if type(ims[0]) is np.ndarray:
        ims = np.array(ims)
        if (ims.shape[-1] != 3):
            ims = ims.transpose((0,2,3,1))
    f = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    cols = len(ims)//rows if len(ims) % 2 == 0 else len(ims)//rows + 1
    for i in range(len(ims)):
        sp = f.add_subplot(rows, cols, i+1)
        sp.axis('Off')
        if titles is not None:
            sp.set_title(titles[i], fontsize=16)
        plt.imshow(ims[i], interpolation=None if interp else 'none')

plots(imgs, titles=labels)
```

gives me the desired output like this: 
[image]
Special thanks to @Andrea

Answer (score 0):

I cannot leave a comment yet, so quick update from my side here.

Using matplotlib 3.4.3 I receive a ValueError.
To fix it just update the for loop definition:

```
for i in range(rows*cols):
   ...
```